# AIR SocketServer cleanup? How to close when app quits?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air, serversocket

I have a simple AIR app that listens on a socket using the SocketServer class.

I have the following code when I first start up the app:

```
if( serverSocket.bound ) 
        {
            serverSocket.close();
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();

        }
        serverSocket.bind( parseInt( localPort ), localIP );
        serverSocket.addEventListener( ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, onConnect );
        serverSocket.listen();
```

However I find that if I try to test my movie after making some quick changes, I can't bind to the same address:port. I'm guessing that somehow that the port is still occupied. I get a "Operation attempted on invalid socket" error.

But if I wait a bit and then test my movie, I can bind to the address:port.

The close() is not taking affect. Can I try to close() this when the user decides to exit the app? Is there some sort of event that allows me to do something before the app quits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the socket is not the same socket instance you had during the previous run of your application. Second, the event you are looking for is

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener( Event.EXITING, this.handler_exit );
```

Call serverSocket.close(); in the event handler. Also might be good to close all client sockets which were opened upon accepting clients.